# Vector equations for a line

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

> A vector equation for the line L is given by $\binom{x}{y} = \binom{4}{4}+\binom{3}{1}t$. Which of the following are also vector equations for the same line L?

Of the choices given (not shown here), $\binom{x}{y} = \binom{4}{4}+\binom{6}{2}t$ and $\binom{x}{y} = \binom{7}{5}+\binom{3}{1}t$ are the vector equations for the same line. But I don't really understand why the first one - $\binom{x}{y} = \binom{4}{4}+\binom{6}{2}t$ - is the same as the original one, and if multiplyinga scalar quantity does not change the line, could such a scalar quantity be negative?

Answer (score 1):

1) Direction vectors must be parallel:

$\vec d_1$ $ = $ $\alpha$ $ \vec d_2$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Example: $(6,2) = 2 (3,1) $,  $\alpha =2$.

2) Check for a common point, e.g. ,

if  the point  $(4,4), t=0,$  first line,  is on the other line,

I.e. if you can find a $ t' $ on the other line

satisfying condition  1)  such that it passes through $( 4,4)$.

Example: $(4,4) = (7,5) + (-1)(3,1),$
 $i.e. t' = -1$.

Recap:

1) Check for parallel direction vectors

2) A common point on the lines.

Comment: If you say parallel direction vectors, then I think it is okay if the scalar multiplied is negative, right? (because then the direction will be changed, but it would still be parallel.)

Comment: The scalar is a real number , you need positive , and negative to "run" the whole straight line, ok?